# Is an SSL certificate required by law on an e-commerce site?

Tags: https, ecommerce, security-certificate

I've inherited a site which sells digital products (videos) using paypal. The cart and checkout pages are not currently served over SSL. The business is UK based but the servers are in the US.

Aside from security concerns (I realise these pages *should* be served over https), is this actually a legal requirement in the UK and / or USA?

Comment: No, its not... But safe guarding your customers data falls under local data protection acts. Not taking reasonable steps to safe guard your customers data is 1. stupid and 2. can be found liable for damages.

Comment: It is not in the U.S. but it might as well be. Certificates have been standard practice for so long that I am amazed that someone had an e-commerce site without a certificate. I would be setting one up right away!! How many people ran away before buying because you do not have a certificate?? You will never know. But I will bet it is a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the payments are totally handled by paypal then they are taking care of this for you.  See this info on PCI DSS compliance

https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/pci

However if you are additionally taking and storing customer details you have additional obligations under the data protection act.

Here is a good roundup...

http://www.amitywebsolutions.co.uk/blog/website-legal-requirements-3-the-data-protection-act